# Can't get desktop environment running

Tags: linux, command-line, gnome, xorg, kde

I am running Sabayon linux, a fork of gentoo. I recently removed KDE according to http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=Remove_KDE this page, and followed through with a reboot. Upon booting, I no longer booted into a graphical environment. Instead, I was stuck in command line. I originally thought this was due to removing something from GNOME in the removal of KDE, but GNOME is updated and fully checked. I also reinstalled KDE, on the off chance that it would help.

As far as feedback from the machine goes, my libtest goes fine, and the deptest reveals that one of my xorg drivers is not there, but it is an older version that the one I currently have.

Anybody have any ideas how I could get back to my GNOME? Or another DE?

Answer (score 0):

First check if your xdm service is enabled:

```
$ /sbin/rc-update show|grep xdm
```

and then, if there was no output:

```
# /sbin/rc-update add xdm
# /etc/init.d/xdm start
```

If xdm was already enabled, then check your /etc/conf.d/xdm:

```
DISPLAYMANAGER="kdm" # for kde
DISPLAYMANAGER="gdm" # for gnome
```

Comment: After trying your advice, I got the response that my xdm was default, and the listing in the conf.d/xdm said that I had gdm enabled. Upon reboot, I still booted into a login prompt from the command line.